# Laptop Adapter plug smoking

Tags: laptop

My duplicate SONY laptop adapter (19.5V 3.9A 90W ) is smoking when I connected to laptop and becomes too hot. But when I unplug it, the adapter is operating normal. What may be the issue here ?

Comment: try a different adaptor and if the different adaptor works you can be sure that other adaptor is faulty.

Comment: Ok. I will try it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Smoke is almost always not a good sign when it comes to delicate electronics. It is usually a symptom of something in the adapter is going through a chemical reaction caused by an excessive heat generated probably by more current passing through a component that can handle. If persisted, this can eventually lead to adapter igniting whatever it's in contact with in it's surrounding, by the heat generated and may lead to a fire.

My guess for the reason why your adapter stops smokings when you unplug is probably because it's control circuit is able to detect that it's disconnected, and shuts itself down by cutting or reducing the current to a level where the chemical reaction cannot be sustained within that time frame.

TL;DR; Adaptor possibly faulty and using it in that state is possibly dangerous. Highly recommend to recycle it and get a new one.

Comment: I checked the adapter to find chemical reaction but found the problem is with the plug wire. Replaced the plug wire and now adapter working fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your laptop is drawing too much current and the over-current protection circuitry in the adapter is not kicking in. Does the laptop work with the other adapter?
You might also try removing the battery to make sure that that's not the culprit.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for suggestion. i need to try it with different adapter.My laptop battery is already drained, running it only through the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you smell the charger hole and it smells like smoke or something burning its probley something to do with the fan breaking, I say you go to the store you got the laptop from and get it checked out